# java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) Over WIFI

Tags: android, web-services, wifi, httpclient, socketexception

When I am sending an image which is converted into string and welcome text with the request. the server do not responds for a long time and response me as  **java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)**

This happens only on wifi .
Please provide any solution for the same .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recomend you to do these sanitary checks to reach to solution to this problem

1. open your browser you are using and try copying the url(used as the request line) and paste it into your browser of your **MOBILE DEVICE** , if you still get the same error or may be **connection refused** that means your MOBILE and YOUR PC on which server runs are not on the same network.

Comment: No it doesn't. There can't be a connection to reset unless there was a connection, and there can't be a connection unless there was a network path between the peers.